# Disable submit button on a form for a certain value of an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, submit

I have create a JSP and i have this form:

```
<form action="Cinema" method="get">
    <select name="IdRoom" id="selectBox">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected> Choose a Cinema </option>         
        <c:forEach items="${listCinema}" var="singleCinema">
            <option value="${singleCinema.idSingleCinema}">${singleCinema.localName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <input id="buttonSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

As the first line ( before the for ) I have add the value as here:

```
<option disabled="disabled" selected> Choose a Cinema </option>
```

When the page is uploaded , if i try to click on the button function it go to call my service ( it shouldn't) , but after i open the drop-down list the first value of my drop-down is disabled correctly.

I need to disable the button Submit for this option when the page is uploaded only for the first value of the Drop-down list ( not for the others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onchange` listener to the `select` and add the disabled attribute to the submit button like this:

```
<select name="IdRoom" id="selectBox" onchange="this.form.buttonSubmit.disabled=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=='your-first-value'">

<input id="buttonSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
```

The `onchange` will be triggered whenever the value of the dropdown is changed. In this case, whenever you select a value, it will check whether the selected value is equal to your first value. If that is the case, the `disabled` attribute of the submit button is set to true otherwise it is set to false.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Hi Varun,
it function perfectly.
I have a question: what does it mean this piece of code:
value=='your-first-value'
I am making this question cause i am not a front-end developer but back-end developer.

Comment: @liriooliro I have added a brief explanation of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("select").on('change',function(){
     if($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "Choose a Cinema")
         $("#buttonSubmit").attr('disabled', true);
     else
         $("#buttonSubmit").attr('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="Cinema" method="get">
    <select name="IdRoom" id="selectBox">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected> Choose a Cinema </option>         
        <c:forEach items="${listCinema}" var="singleCinema">
            <option value="${singleCinema.idSingleCinema}">${singleCinema.localName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <input id="buttonSubmit" disabled="disabled" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```